# Looking for a way to color ONLY the currently shown web page Tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm looking for a way to color ONLY the currently shown web page tab. I see that Firefox has a ton of Tab related add-ons. But they are all overkill and dotn do what I need. I simply want Firefox to Color the tab I'm currently viewing. I frequently have multiple tabs open and its tricky to see what tab is selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to install an alternative theme that will highlight your opened tab better.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/themes/

Perhaps something like this one?

[image]

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I was looking for, but it works. I usually avoid themes because they are so gaudy. But yours are nice. Thanks.